# How can I get data from a firebase app when a user logs in

Tags: javascript, firebase

Ok, so I have a website with a forum that is using firebase to hold the data for the forum posts and the user data to login.  The problem I am having is pulling data from the users child when they log on so that the forum can use that data.  When the user creates their account, they create a username along with email and password.  What I want to do is display that username in the forum whenever they add a post, but whatever I try just doesn't seem to be pulling the username from firebase.  When the user logs in, I want the data to be sent from my login controller to a service.js file so that all my separate controllers and html pages can see the username data and display what I need.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using angular...I think?

If so, you can save the returned login data to the $rootScope, or even better use localstorage. Then just access it from one of those when needed.

```
// Create a callback to handle the result of the authentication
function authHandler(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
    $rootScope.user = authData.uid;
  }
}

// Authenticate users with a custom Firebase token
ref.authWithCustomToken("<token>", authHandler);

// Alternatively, authenticate users anonymously
ref.authAnonymously(authHandler);

// Or with an email/password combination
ref.authWithPassword({
  email    : 'bobtony@firebase.com',
  password : 'correcthorsebatterystaple'
}, authHandler);
```

Comment: Yes I am using angular, and I have $rootScope set up, but what is the code I need to use to save the returned data? Can you give me an example please?

Comment: edit to show example, firebase code from: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html

Comment: Ok I pretty much have all of that, but it is still not pulling the data I'm trying to get.  here is how the data looks in firebase:
-App:
    -users
       -simplelogin:15
           name: "Kevin" 
           uid: simplelogin:15

Like I said I'm trying to pull the name child out of the user, but all the code I try to implement doesn't get the data:
ref.child('users').child(authData.name); or
just $rootScope.user = authData.name.
Does authData not go deep enough to get the name child?

Comment: Ok so I tried something different.  When the user registers, I have the uid set to the username the user inputs, so now in firebase it displays like this:
-App: -users -Kevin -uid:"Kevin"
But in the forum when it displays, it says "user: simplelogin:15" is that a security rule implementation?

Comment: I think the way Firebase handles saving user data, you would need to access it from the uid object. So `$rootScope.user = authData.uid.name;` would access the name. If you look at https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html you'll see the save name and profile to the uid like so: `ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).set({
      provider: authData.provider,
      name: getName(authData)
    });`

Comment: And yes that is a security rule implementation. So your user 'Kevin' is simple login uid number 15

Comment: So your name data is a child of 'simplelogin:15' : { ... }